# SQL syntax error in this part: "int not null auto_increment,"

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I create a physical model in powerdesigner 
and then generate the code for mysql5, and now in
 phpmyadmin Im getting an error:

```
#1064 - You have an 
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'create table CARD
```

Do you see why this can be happening?

Im creating my tables like this:

```
create table books
(
   COD_BOOK           int not null auto_increment,
   TITLE_BOOK         varchar(50),
   ISBN   _BOOK        varchar(20),
   CATEGORY_BOOK           varchar(20),
   primary key (COD_BOOK)
)
```

And the problem seems like is in this part: `int not null auto_increment,`

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the semi-colon at the end of your create statement. This makes the first line of the create statement for the next table an error which is what that error message is trying to tell you.

```
create table books
(
   COD_BOOK int not null auto_increment,
   TITLE_BOOK varchar(50),
   ISBN_BOOK varchar(20),
   CATEGORY_BOOK varchar(20),
   primary key (COD_BOOK)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space after `ISBN`:

```
create table books
(
   COD_BOOK           int not null auto_increment,
   TITLE_BOOK         varchar(50),
   ISBN_BOOK          varchar(20),
   CATEGORY_BOOK      varchar(20),
   primary key (COD_BOOK)
)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe87b) is a SQL Fiddle.